# Specify arabic numerals in \ref{}

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I've two documents, `doc1` references lists in `doc2` through package `xr`.
In `doc2` the lists are numbered with arabic numbers, but when referenced in `doc1` using `\ref{tag}` they show up as roman numbers. How can I change this? I'd like to use arabic numbers always.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,final]{ProjectStyle}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii} }

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.\theenumii}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Convites para conferencias, coloquio e SOC}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item {\label{inv_leiden} Comprovante para \emph{Fine Tunning Stellar Population Models} (Leiden, 2006)}
    \item {\label{inv_iau} Comprovante para \emph{XII Latin American Regional IAU Meeting} (Isla Margarita, 2007)}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Ref: \ref{inv_leiden}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I get:

enumii0..

1. Convites para conferencias, coloquio e SOC

1.1 Comprovante para Fine Tunning Stellar Population Models (Lei- den, 2006)

1.2 Comprovante para XII Latin American Regional IAU Meeting (Isla Margarita, 2007)

Ref: 1a

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The external reference to a document using `xr` should be the same as you get from a reference within the document (it just reads the value from the `aux` file.

`\ref` does not use `\labelenumi` at all that just affects the label used in the list display.
For the first level list it uses `\theenumi` and for second level list it uses `\p@enumii\theenumii`.

You were missing a `\makeatletter` and and had the prefix including enumii twice, your MWE can not be run as it uses a local class but you see the same with `book` class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,final]{book}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii} }

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Convites para conferencias, coloquio e SOC}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item {\label{inv_leiden} Comprovante para \emph{Fine Tunning Stellar Population Models} (Leiden, 2006)}
    \item {\label{inv_iau} Comprovante para \emph{XII Latin American Regional IAU Meeting} (Isla Margarita, 2007)}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Ref: \ref{inv_leiden}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still didn't understand how to fix it. The default for numbering lists is roman. I had set to have it arabic. Nevertheless the info in .aux is still in roman, therefore both docs will reference it as roman (be it external or within), which I don't want. How do I redefine so that numbers in the aux file are given in arabic as well?

Comment: as I say if you redefine `\label...` it has no effect on the aux file or on `\ref` you need to define `\theenumii` and `\p@enumii` If you make a minimal complete document using book class and showing the problem it would be much easier to show you how to fix it if the above is not enough. Questions should _laways_ include a complete example document.

Comment: I edited the question to contain an example.

Comment: @user26836 code added

Answer (score 0):

The following worked well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,final]{ProjectStyle}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii} }

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Convites para conferencias, coloquio e SOC}
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\label{inv_leiden} Comprovante para \emph{Fine Tunning Stellar Population Models} (Leiden, 2006)}
\item {\label{inv_iau} Comprovante para \emph{XII Latin American Regional IAU Meeting} (Isla Margarita, 2007)}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Ref: \ref{inv_leiden}

\end{document}
```